# Move to another folder after downloading new messages in K-9 mail app

Tags: java, android, email, imap

I've got a mailing client based on K-9 mail. I added new function to automatically check either the message is sent from certain e-mail address and to store it in custom folder.

This is changes to LocalFolder.java
Source code: 
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/master/k9mail/src/main/java/com/fsck/k9/mailstore/LocalFolder.java

I am checking rule with this:

```
public Message checkRule(Message message,String body)
{
    int state = 0;
    lstFolder.clear();
    if (Globals.lst_rules == null)
    {
        lstFolder.add(String.valueOf(mFolderId));
        return message;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < Globals.lst_rules.size();i++)
    {
        state = 0;
        RuleDBManager.RuleModel rule = Globals.lst_rules.get(i);
        String pattern = rule.word;
        List<String> ptList = parsePattern(pattern);

        int condition = rule.condition;
        int action = rule.action;
        String container = "";
        container = Address.pack(message.getFrom()).toLowerCase();
        }
        for (int j = 0;j < ptList.size();j++) {
            if (container.contains(ptList.get(j).toLowerCase())) {
                lstFolder.add(String.valueOf(rule.folderId));
                }
                state = 1;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (state != 1) {
            lstFolder.add(String.valueOf(mFolderId));
        }
    }
    if (lstFolder.size() == 0)
    {
        lstFolder.add(String.valueOf(mFolderId));
    }

    return message;
```

I changed this part of code:

```
MessageInfoExtractor messageExtractor = new MessageInfoExtractor(localStore.context, message);
        String preview = messageExtractor.getMessageTextPreview();
        int attachmentCount = messageExtractor.getAttachmentCount();

        long rootMessagePartId = saveMessageParts(db, message);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("message_part_id", rootMessagePartId);
        cv.put("uid", uid);
        cv.put("subject", message.getSubject());
        cv.put("sender_list", Address.pack(message.getFrom()));
        cv.put("date", message.getSentDate() == null
                ? System.currentTimeMillis() : message.getSentDate().getTime());
        cv.put("flags", this.localStore.serializeFlags(message.getFlags()));
        cv.put("deleted", message.isSet(Flag.DELETED) ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put("read", message.isSet(Flag.SEEN) ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put("flagged", message.isSet(Flag.FLAGGED) ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put("answered", message.isSet(Flag.ANSWERED) ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put("forwarded", message.isSet(Flag.FORWARDED) ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put("folder_id", mFolderId);
        cv.put("to_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)));
        cv.put("cc_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.CC)));
        cv.put("bcc_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.BCC)));
        cv.put("preview", preview);
        cv.put("reply_to_list", Address.pack(message.getReplyTo()));
        cv.put("attachment_count", attachmentCount);
        cv.put("internal_date", message.getInternalDate() == null
                ? System.currentTimeMillis() : message.getInternalDate().getTime());
        cv.put("mime_type", message.getMimeType());
        cv.put("empty", 0);

        String messageId = message.getMessageId();
        if (messageId != null) {
            cv.put("message_id", messageId);
        }

        if (oldMessageId == -1) {
            long msgId = db.insert("messages", "uid", cv);

            // Create entry in 'threads' table
            cv.clear();
            cv.put("message_id", msgId);

            if (rootId != -1) {
                cv.put("root", rootId);
            }
            if (parentId != -1) {
                cv.put("parent", parentId);
            }

            db.insert("threads", null, cv);
        } else {
            db.update("messages", cv, "id = ?", new String[] { Long.toString(oldMessageId) });
        }
```

To this:

```
for (int p = 0; p < lstFolder.size(); p++) {
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                cv.put("uid", uid);
                                cv.put("subject", message.getSubject());
                                cv.put("sender_list", Address.pack(message.getFrom()));
                                cv.put("date", message.getSentDate() == null
                                        ? System.currentTimeMillis() : message.getSentDate().getTime());
                                cv.put("flags", LocalFolder.this.localStore.serializeFlags(message.getFlags()));
                                cv.put("deleted", message.isSet(Flag.DELETED) ? 1 : 0);
                                cv.put("read", message.isSet(Flag.SEEN) ? 1 : 0);
                                cv.put("flagged", message.isSet(Flag.FLAGGED) ? 1 : 0);
                                cv.put("answered", message.isSet(Flag.ANSWERED) ? 1 : 0);
                                cv.put("forwarded", message.isSet(Flag.FORWARDED) ? 1 : 0);
                                //cv.put("folder_id", mFolderId);
                                cv.put("folder_id", lstFolder.get(p));
                                cv.put("to_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)));
                                cv.put("cc_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.CC)));
                                cv.put("bcc_list", Address.pack(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.BCC)));
                                cv.put("html_content", html.length() > 0 ? html : null);
                                cv.put("text_content", text.length() > 0 ? text : null);
                                cv.put("preview", preview.length() > 0 ? preview : null);
                                cv.put("reply_to_list", Address.pack(message.getReplyTo()));
                                cv.put("attachment_count", attachments.size());
                                cv.put("internal_date", message.getInternalDate() == null
                                        ? System.currentTimeMillis() : message.getInternalDate().getTime());
                                cv.put("mime_type", message.getMimeType());
                                cv.put("empty", 0);

                                String messageId = message.getMessageId();
                                if (messageId != null) {
                                    cv.put("message_id", messageId);
                                }

                                long msgId;

                                if (oldMessageId == -1) {
                                    msgId = db.insert("messages", "uid", cv);

                                    // Create entry in 'threads' table
                                    cv.clear();
                                    cv.put("message_id", msgId);

                                    if (rootId != -1) {
                                        cv.put("root", rootId);
                                    }
                                    if (parentId != -1) {
                                        cv.put("parent", parentId);
                                    }

                                    db.insert("threads", null, cv);
                                } else {
                                    db.update("messages", cv, "id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(oldMessageId)});
                                    msgId = oldMessageId;
                                }

                                if (attachments.size() == 2) {
                                    saveAttachment(msgId, attachments.get(0), false);
                                } else if (attachments.size() > 0)
                                    saveAttachment(msgId, attachments.get(0), false);
                                saveHeaders(msgId, (MimeMessage) message);
                            }
```

But when I click on message, I get a NullPointerException in this part of code

```
public Message storeSmallMessage(final Message message, final Runnable runnable) throws MessagingException {
    return this.localStore.database.execute(true, new DbCallback<Message>() {
        @Override
        public Message doDbWork(final SQLiteDatabase db) throws WrappedException, UnavailableStorageException {
            try {
                appendMessages(Collections.singletonList(message));
                final String uid = message.getUid();
                final Message result = getMessage(uid);
                Log.e("g",result.toString());
                runnable.run();
                //CheckRuleMove(message);
                // Set a flag indicating this message has now be fully downloaded
//result.setFlag get this Exception probably because "result" is Null
                result.setFlag(Flag.X_DOWNLOADED_FULL, true);
                return result;
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new WrappedException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

"Result" was got from this part:

```
public LocalMessage getMessage(final String uid) throws MessagingException {
    try {
        return this.localStore.database.execute(false, new DbCallback<LocalMessage>() {
            @Override
            public LocalMessage doDbWork(final SQLiteDatabase db) throws WrappedException, UnavailableStorageException {
                try {
                    open(OPEN_MODE_RW);
                    LocalMessage message = new LocalMessage(LocalFolder.this.localStore, uid, LocalFolder.this);
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = db.rawQuery(
                                     "SELECT " +
                                     LocalStore.GET_MESSAGES_COLS +
                                     "FROM messages " +
                                     "LEFT JOIN threads ON (threads.message_id = messages.id) " +
                                     "WHERE uid = ? AND folder_id = ?",
                                new String[] {
                                         message.getUid(), Long.toString(mFolderId)
                                     });
                        Log.e("hey",cursor.toString());
                        if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        message.populateFromGetMessageCursor(cursor);
                    } finally {
                        Utility.closeQuietly(cursor);
                    }
                    return message;
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new WrappedException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (WrappedException e) {
        throw(MessagingException) e.getCause();
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, mFolderId (Id of refreshing folder) doesn't equal lstFolder.get(0) (Folder, where message is saved) for server and I can't synchronize e-mail folder and my client folder.
The question is how to improve my code so I could move a message to another folder on server at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in MessagingController.class - queueMoveOrCopy